# Find reason of error 500 when adding comments WP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have error 500 when commenting posts. No logged errors on my nginx and php logs. How to find reason of error 500 on wp-comments-posting.php file?

Thank for all your advices, regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Start here: [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest to turn the php display errors and also edit the 'wp-config.php' and enable the 'define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );' instead of been set to 'false' which will display the reason for the '500' which might be coming from a plugin or something else that needs to be looked in. We will be awaiting your next update on what has been displayed after you have enabled the error/debugging .

Answer (score 0):

try to disable your plugin or theme first, and if you still see error notice, try to enable debug as suggested by the previous answer